# Incremental OTA zip is not generating

Tags: android, embedded, android-source, ota

I am trying to generate minor.zip(Incremental OTA zip)file.

> Home$build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -i
>   out/target/product/xxx/OTA_20170916.zip
>   out/target/product/xxx/OTA-20171010.zip
>   out/target/product/xxx/minor.zip

```
unzipping target target-files...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 2028, in 
<module>
main(sys.argv[1:])
File "build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1937, in 
main
OPTIONS.info_dict = common.LoadInfoDict(input_zip)
File "build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 141, in LoadInfoDict
raise ValueError("can't find recovery API version in input target-files")
ValueError: can't find recovery API version in input target-files
```

This error is coming...

I followed this site http://solarex.github.io/wiki/Android/android_ota_update.html

Could you please help to overcome this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got solution for incremental OTA zip creation.

Step 1: Copy new OTA and old OTA zip files from out/target/product/xxx/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/

Step 2: ./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files -i old.zip new.zip update.zip

Incremental OTA file will be generate.